# SQL - Selecting all latest unique records

Tags: sql, ms-access, excel, vba

I'm struggling a bit at creating an SQL query to select some records from an Access Database (using Excel VBA).

A cut of one of the tables (let's call it 'table1') has the following columns:

```
| my_id | your_id | phase |

| 1     | 1       | Open  |

| 2     | 1       | Close |

| 3     | 2       | Open  |

| 4     | 3       | Close |

| 5     | 2       | Close |

| 6     | 3       | Open  |
```

The field 'my_id' will always be a unique value whereas the 'your_id' field may contain duplicates.

What I would like to do is select everything from the table for the most recent record of the 'your_id' where the phase is 'Close'. So that means in the above example table it would select 5, 4 & 2.

Hope this makes sense, sorry if not - I'm struggling to articulate what I mean!

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain `most recent record` in the given table, i mean which records to exclude other than Phase <> 'Close'

Comment: Thanks for you comment - solved now with the answer from Nitin below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although from ur example if u just add where conditin as phase='Close' u will get the records of 5,4 and 2. But I am assuming that there might be scenarios (not in ur example) where more than 1 record can come with status as Close for any given your_id so query should look like this

```
 Select * from table1 where my_id in (
   Select Max(My_Id) from table1 where phase='Close' group by your_id)
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks! Thanks also for managing to interpret my vague question!